# I want to get the total amount of incomes in my Firebase collection based on the current user in real-time

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can retrieve the total sum of all the amounts in my revenue collection, but I'm unable to do it based on the data provided by the logged-in user.

[image: my firebase collection]

Here is my code:

```
func calculatedAmount() {
    let firestoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
    
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        
        let userIncomeCollection = firestoreDatabase.collection("incomes").whereField("userID", isEqualTo: currentUserID)
        
        userIncomeCollection.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Hata: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                var totalAmount = 1

                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    if  let amount = document.get("amount") as? Int {
                        totalAmount += amount
                    }
                }

                self.mainAccountLabel.text = "\(totalAmount)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but shouldn’t it be `var totalAmount = 0`?

Comment: Yes it should be.I tried this for see the result so my first code totalAmount = 1 it didn’t change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collection -> Documents -> UserId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJd3.png)
Theres no "userID" property in your documents. You need to add a userID property to your documents, you cant query the docs of a collection based on their document id itself. (Or at least thats what I see you are trying to do).

Heres a pic of my [FireStore DB pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJd3.png)

```
    static func fetchUserStats(uid: String, completion: @escaping(UserStats) -> Void) {

    Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        
        let posts = snapshot?.documents.count ?? 0
        
        completion(UserStats(followers: followers, following: following, posts: posts))
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't notice the mistake due to distraction, it's been resolved.

Comment: Sure bro, no pb!